# React-native ask iOS to enable wifi

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I don't find a way to check if wifi is enabled on iOS.
I am currently creating tracking app and to increase user location we need wifi enabled.
So I want to ask user to enable wifi, but I want to check if it's currently enabled or not.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

With https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo you can check it by:

```
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});
```

Comment: It checks connection type, but I don't need user to be connected, just to check if wifi service is enabled. For example it could use mobile data, but we need wifi enabled to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check connection type :-

```
 NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  this.setState({
    connType: state.type
  })
 });
```

If connection type is wifi then ok if not you can display some popup to enable wifi.

You can use the following code to open settings, so user can easily enable their wifi

```
  openWiFi = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
    }else{
        // import DeviceSettings from 'react-native-device-settings';
        DeviceSettings.wifi();
    }
   }
```

Comment: It shows connection type, but I could be connected to mobile data and I need that wifi would be enabled too. So it would not solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired status by below method. Write this method in native & access from React Native by using promise.
Refer:https://francescocrema.it/check-wifi-status-on-ios-in-swift/

```
func isWiFiOn() -> Bool {
        var address : String?
        var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
        if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
            var ptr = ifaddr
            while ptr != nil {
                defer { ptr = ptr.memory.ifa_next }
                let interface = ptr.memory
                let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.memory.sa_family
                if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {
                    if let name = String.fromCString(interface.ifa_name) where name == "awdl0" {
                        if((Int32(interface.ifa_flags) & IFF_UP) == IFF_UP) {
                            return(true)
                        }
                        else {
                            return(false)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
        }
        return (false)
    }
```